# Get time difference between row values grouped by event

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using Postgres 9.3.3

I have a table with multiple events, two of them are "AVAILABLE" and "UNAVAILABLE". These events are assigned to a specific object. There are also other object ids in this table (removed for clarity):

[image]

What I need is the "available" time per day, something like that:
[image]

Comment: Postgresql version? `select version()`

Comment: [Various Fixes in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24699608/131874)

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/69888/2)

```
select
    object_id, day,
    sum(upper(available) - lower(available)) as available
from (
    select
        g.object_id, date_trunc('day', d) as day,
        (
            available *
            tsrange(date_trunc('day', d), date_trunc('day', d)::date + 1, '[)')
        ) as available
    from
        (
            select
                object_id, event,
                tsrange(
                    timestamp,
                    lead(timestamp) over(
                        partition by object_id order by timestamp
                    ),
                    '[)'
                ) as available
            from events
            where event in ('AVAILABLE', 'UNAVAILABLE')
        ) s
        right join
        (
            generate_series(
                (select min(timestamp) from events),
                (select max(timestamp) from events),
                '1 day'
            ) g (d) 
            cross join
            (select distinct object_id from events) s
        ) g on
            tsrange(date_trunc('day', d), date_trunc('day', d)::date + 1, '[)') && available and
            (event = 'AVAILABLE' or event is null) and
            g.object_id = s.object_id
) s
group by 1, 2
order by 1, 2
```

psql output

```
 object_id |         day         | available 
-----------+---------------------+-----------
         1 | 1970-01-02 00:00:00 | 12:00:00
         1 | 1970-01-03 00:00:00 | 12:00:00
         1 | 1970-01-04 00:00:00 | 
         1 | 1970-01-05 00:00:00 | 1 day
         1 | 1970-01-06 00:00:00 | 1 day
         1 | 1970-01-07 00:00:00 | 12:00:00
```

Table DDL

```
create table events (
    object_id int,
    event text,
    timestamp timestamp
);
insert into events (object_id, event, timestamp) values
(1, 'AVAILABLE', '1970-01-02 12:00:00'),
(1, 'UNAVAILABLE', '1970-01-03 12:00:00'),
(1, 'AVAILABLE', '1970-01-05 00:00:00'),
(1, 'UNAVAILABLE', '1970-01-07 12:00:00');
```

Comment: Won't work on busy days (where there are multiple `available` periods)  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e47b6/1 -- but not sure OP has data like that.

Answer (score 1):

Your example output suggests that you want all your objects to be returned, but grouped. If that is the case, this query can do that

```
select object_id, day, sum(upper(tsrange) - lower(tsrange))
from (
  select object_id, date(day) as day, e.tsrange * tsrange(day, day + interval '1' day) tsrange
  from generate_series(timestamp '1970-01-01', '1970-01-07', interval '1' day) day
  left join (
    select object_id,
           case event
             when 'AVAILABLE' then tsrange(timestamp, lead(timestamp) over (partition by object_id order by timestamp))
             else null
           end tsrange
    from events
    where event in ('AVAILABLE', 'UNAVAILABLE')
  ) e on e.tsrange && tsrange(day, day + interval '1' day)
) d
group by object_id, day
order by day, object_id
```

But that will output something like that (if you have multiple `object_id`s):

```
 object_id | day          | sum
-----------+--------------+-----------
           | '1970-01-01' |
     1     | '1970-01-02' | '12:00:00'
     1     | '1970-01-03' | '12:00:00'
           | '1970-01-04' |
     1     | '1970-01-05' | '1 day'
     1     | '1970-01-06' | '1 day'
     2     | '1970-01-06' | '12:00:00'
     1     | '1970-01-07' | '12:00:00'
```

In my opinion it would make much more sense, if you would query just one object at a time:

```
select day, sum(upper(tsrange) - lower(tsrange))
from (
  select date(day) as day, e.tsrange * tsrange(day, day + interval '1' day) tsrange
  from generate_series(timestamp '1970-01-01', '1970-01-07', interval '1' day) day
  left join (
    select case event
             when 'AVAILABLE' then tsrange(timestamp, lead(timestamp) over (partition by object_id order by timestamp))
             else null
           end tsrange
    from events
    where event in ('AVAILABLE', 'UNAVAILABLE')
    and object_id = 1
  ) e on e.tsrange && tsrange(day, day + interval '1' day)
) d
group by day
order by day
```

This will output something, like:

```
 day          | sum
--------------+----------
 '1970-01-01' |
 '1970-01-02' | '12:00:00'
 '1970-01-03' | '12:00:00'
 '1970-01-04' |
 '1970-01-05' | '1 day'
 '1970-01-06' | '1 day'
 '1970-01-07' | '12:00:00'
```

I used this schema/data for my outputs:

```
create table events (
  object_id int,
  event text,
  timestamp timestamp
);

insert into events (object_id, event, timestamp)
values (1, 'AVAILABLE', '1970-01-02 12:00:00'),
       (1, 'UNAVAILABLE', '1970-01-03 12:00:00'),
       (1, 'AVAILABLE', '1970-01-05 00:00:00'),
       (1, 'UNAVAILABLE', '1970-01-07 12:00:00'),
       (2, 'AVAILABLE', '1970-01-06 00:00:00'),
       (2, 'UNAVAILABLE', '1970-01-06 06:00:00'),
       (2, 'AVAILABLE', '1970-01-06 12:00:00'),
       (2, 'UNAVAILABLE', '1970-01-06 18:00:00');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer.  If we assume that the next event after available is unavailable, then `lead()` comes to the rescue and the following is a start:

```
select object_id, to_char(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as day,
       to_char(nextts - timestamp, 'HH24:MI') as interval
from (select t.*,
             lead(timestamp) over (partition by object_id order by timestamp) as nextts
      from table t
      where event in ('AVAILABLE', 'UNAVAILABLE')
     ) t
where event = 'AVAILABLE'
group by object_id, to_char(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

I suspect, though, that when the interval spans multiple days, you want to split the days into separate parts.  This becomes more of a challenge.

Comment: "I suspect, though, that when the interval spans multiple days, you want to split the days into separate parts."

Yes thats right

Comment: Do you have a calendar table?

Comment: No, unfortunately not